# Mails i receive from my webdite contact form doesnt display the correct senders email address

Tags: php

I cant reply to mails from my website contact form because when I receive it on my hostinger webmail, the 'from' shows: u6078891...@us-imm-web124.main-hosting.eu instead of the sender's email address. I need your help with this please

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "info@mydomain.com";
$yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
$subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Write a subject");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Write your comments");
$email = $full_name.'<'.$email.'>';

if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
$message = "Hello!
You have received a message from your website:
Name: $yourname
Subject: $subject
E-mail: $email
Message: $comments
End of message
";

$headers = 'From: ' .$email. "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

header('Location: thanks.html');
exit();

function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use the submitter's address as the from address; It's forgery and will probably result in your messages being bounced or spam-filtered. Use your own address as the from address and put the submitter's address in a reply-to header.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the headers but you have not included them, therefore mail() uses server settings.

```
mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: You are the best. Wow you nailed that. Its perfect. Thanks